# Appending and Casting Location Info from Contentful API

Tags: swiftui, contentful

I'm having trouble with the syntax of appending the latitude and longitude from Contentful. The latlong line seems to be crashing my preview in Xcode. What is the correct way to get the data and cast it? Thank you so much.

Edit: the error I'm getting is returned nil on the latlong line.

```
class CourseStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var courses: [Course] = courseData
    
    init() {
        let colors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.3647058904, green: 0.06666667014, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627715, green: 0.3529411852, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.9098039269, green: 0.4784313738, blue: 0.6431372762, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627477, green: 0.6588235497, blue: 0.5450980663, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.2588235438, green: 0.7568627596, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.5725490451, green: 0, blue: 0.2313725501, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.9372549057, green: 0.3490196168, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1)]
        var index = 0
        
        getArray(id: "course") { (items) in
            items.forEach { (item) in
                self.courses.append(Course(
                    title: item.fields["title"] as! String,
                    subtitle: item.fields["subtitle"] as! String,
                    latlong: item.fields["Latlong"] as! Float,
                    image: item.fields.linkedAsset(at: "image")?.url ?? URL(string: "")!,
                    logo: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Logo1"),
                    color: colors[index],
                    show: false))
                
                index = index + 1
            }
        }
    }
}


//Course Struct
    struct Course: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var subtitle: String
//  var latlong: Float
    var image: URL
    var logo: UIImage
    var color: UIColor
    var show: Bool
}

var courseData = [
    Course(title: "Test", subtitle: "test", image: URL(string: "test")!, logo: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Logo1"), color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.3647058904, green: 0.06666667014, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1), show: false)

//getArray function
func getArray(id: String, completion: @escaping([Entry]) -> ()) {
    let query = Query.where(contentTypeId: id)
    
    client.fetchArray(of: Entry.self, matching: query) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let array):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(array.items)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us the code for your `getArray` and `Course` so we 
can help you debug this. A sample data set would also be helpful. Note, it is not a good idea to use "!" in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response workingdog. I updated the code.

Comment: What is your data set? Latitude and longitude should be separate variables of type `Double`.

Comment: Your updated code is a good start, but there are still too many parts missing to 
be able to reproduce your issue. Add enough `code` and `data` so we can reproduce your problem.
Show us some sample data (and Entry) that would help a lot.